Function output recursion
please tell me how to rework the function so that its output is the opposite. When entering the value -105, it should output (7 5 3), but for me it outputs (3 5 7).
#include <stdio.h>
 
void simpleFactors(unsigned int a, unsigned int last, unsigned int n);
void printFactor(unsigned int last, unsigned int n);
 
int main()
{
    unsigned int a;
    
    scanf("%u", &a);
 
    simpleFactors(a, 2, 0);
 
    printf("\n");
 
    return 0;
}
void simpleFactors(unsigned int a, unsigned int last, unsigned int n)
{
    if (a % last == 0)
    {
        if (a > 1)
            simpleFactors(a / last, last, n + 1); 
    }
    
    else
    {
        printFactor(last, n); 
        
        if (a == 1) return;
 
        if (last * last > a)
        { 
            printf("%ld ", a);
            return; 
        }
        simpleFactors(a, last + 1, 0);
        printf("\n");
        
    }
}
 
void printFactor(unsigned int last, unsigned int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return;
    if (n == 1)
        printf("%ld ", last);
    else
       printf("%ld^%ld ", last, n);
}

I made some small changes in function. This program should pass some tests. I am interested in the correct output when entering the number 105. I managed to reverse the output, but now the program outputs (7 5), without the third digit.
void simpleFactors(unsigned int a, unsigned int last, unsigned int n)
{

    if (a % last == 0)

    {
        if (a > 1)
            simpleFactors(a / last, last, n+1);
    }

    else
    {
        if (last > a) {
            printFactor(last, n);
        }

        if (a == 1) return;

        if (last * last > a)
        {
            printf("%ld ", a);
            printFactor(last, n);
            return;
        }

        simpleFactors(a, last + 1, 0);
        printf("\n");
    }

}


Print the number after the recursive call instead of before.

Can you give more details? Please.

You mean that you need to output the function printFactor() in another place.

You must print the result after it is computed, but you have 2 returns in the function and also after them you need to print. You must remove the returns.
And "%ld" is the format to print long int, the format "%u" is the one to print unsigned int.
void  simpleFactors( unsigned int a, unsigned int last, unsigned int n ) {
    if ( a % last == 0 ) {
        if ( a > 1 ) {
            simpleFactors( a / last, last, n+1 );
        }
    }
    else {
        if ( a != 1 ) {
            if ( last * last > a ) {
                printf( "%u ", a );
            }
            else {
                simpleFactors( a, last+1, 0 );
            }
        }
        printFactor( last, n );
    } 
}
void  printFactor( unsigned int last, unsigned int n ) {
    if ( n == 0 )
        return;
    if ( n == 1 )
        printf( "%u ", last );
    else
        printf( "%u^%u ", last, n );
}

